# KSQLDB Cluster http call fails in K8s with more than one container in Deployement

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, ksqldb

So I have a problem with Clustering KSQLDB (0.27.1, 0.26.0, 0.11.0) with K8s (v1.23.8, v1.24.)

Using a k8s Deployment I start 2 or 3 (replicas:) KSQLDB containers (image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:latest). So all instances have the same "bootstrap.servers" and "ksql.service.id". Backing them is a Kafka Statefulset with 3 instances.

I run my script to build the STREAMS and TABLES in one of the containers. Then add some data to Kafka.

I can query (http) and see my aggregations, **but only if the service with the KSQLDB endpoints hits the machine where I ran the scripts building the STREAMS and TABLES**.
If I log in to the containers that get the error and go to the KSQL --> CLI and I query for the same record it returns with the correct result, so I know the cluster is working.
The problem is that It's just http that does not work when there is a second, third, ... container in the replicaset.

I even tried a helm chart to test this and the same issue appeared.

https://ricardo-aires.github.io/helm-charts/charts/ksqldb/

helm install --set kafka.enabled=false --set kafka.bootstrapServers=PLAINTEXT://my-kafka-k8s-cluster:9092 --set replicaCount=2 --set image.tag=0.27.1 ktool rhcharts/ksqldb